# Leftovers from knitr

Tags: r, knitr, cran, vignette

I am using `knitr` to write a vignette for my package. In `R CMD CHECK` I got the following NOTE:

```
The following directories look like leftovers from 'knitr'
  ‘cache’, ‘figure’
```

These are indeed directories created by `knitr`. But I don't understand how I can remove these after knitting the document into .pdf.

I found one related issue on [github](https://github.com/rOpenGov/eurostat/issues/44) but no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to put

```
figure$
cache$
```

in a `.Rbuildignore` file in the main package directory.  This only works if you `R CMD check` on a built tarball rather than on the package source directory, but that's recommended as best practice anyway ... and it's effectively (I think) what the "Check" button in RStudio does, i.e. calling `devtools::check`, which

> automatically **builds and** checks a source package, using all known best practices

(emphasis added).